# Is there a way to read the TrimBox and BleedBox dimensions from iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there a way to read the TrimBox and BleedBox dimensions from iTextSharp as seen in Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have figured this out myself:

use: iTextSharp.text.Rectangle boxRectangle = pdfReader.GetBoxSize(pageNumber, "trim");

This works for "trim", "bleed", "crop", "art" as [more info here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/PDF/iTextSharp/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPage.cs.htm)

(I was doing a PdfName.TRIMBOX.ToString() which seemed obvious, but is wrong)